# Не находится файл, загружаемый через файловый параметр пайплайна Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Пытаюсь загрузить json-файл через файловый параметр пайплайна Jenkins. Однако в воркспейсе в итоге пусто. Пытался в поле "Местоположение файла" файлового параметра писать нечто вроде $WORKSPACE/myFile.json - безрезультатно (при попытке обратиться по этому пути получаю NoSuchFileException). Знаю, что в Jenkins имеется ряд проблем, связанных с работой файлового параметра - но, возможно, есть какие-то пути решения этой проблемы? Я в Jenkins новичок, поэтому буду благодарен за любой совет.

Comment: А файл то вообще есть? Права на него?

Comment: @BogdanLavreniuk, да, есть и то, и другое.

Comment: если файл не найден, значит, его нет. почему вы решили, что он есть на той node, где вы пытаетесь его прочитать?